# AddListener in foreach

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach, lambda

Suddenly problem with lambda in foreach statement:

```
IEnumerator RefreshNextFrame( Part Current )
{
    yield return null;
    if( Current.Nodes == null )
        yield break;
    Current.Nodes.ForEach( n => Debug.Log( n.name ) );//outputs node0, node1
    for( int i = 0; i < Current.Nodes.Count; i++ )
    {
        Node node = Current.Nodes[i];
        Button button = Instantiate( Resources.Load<GameObject>( "Prefabs/Button" ) ).GetComponent<Button>();
        button.transform.SetParent( content );
        button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = node.name;
        button.onClick.AddListener( delegate
        {
            Debug.Log( button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text );
        } );
    }
}
```

Clicking on buttons always output `node1`

Comment: Try to put the line **Current.Nodes.ForEach( n => Debug.Log( n.name ) );** into the lambda expression to see if both nodes still have the names you expect. Maybe you overwrite them later somewhere else in the code without knowing.

Comment: Nope. Names as I expect.

Comment: This code is in couroutine. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Try to put **button.** before **GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text** in the lambda expression. Maybe you're not even getting the child from the button but from the object in which this code is. So the line would look like this: **Debug.Log( button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text );**

Comment: Yep, that was not right, but now it is *node1* output on all buttons. Same issue.

Comment: So what happens if you DON'T use the lambda expression? Does it work then?

Comment: How can I not use lambda in this situation?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the Unity framework that well. I just tested your situation in a simple C# WPF project and it worked correctly, so I guess the problem has something to do with Unity. I would suggest that you move your question over to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything because of this code is in couroutine. Here is the answer http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/974195/view.html

Comment: Interesting, so lambda inside lambda does not copy the context. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just assign to a new local variable on each iteration and use that local variable for the AddListener.

EDIT
Quick example:

MyFunction will always receive 100 as the value of i on this:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => MyFunction(i));
}
```

But if you do this it will work correctly:

```
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    int iLocal = i;
    button.onClick.AddListener(() => MyFunction(iLocal));
}
```

Comment: We already discussed that, it doesn't work because his code is being executed in an Unity couroutine, which for itself is already some kind of lambda expression with a saved context. Creating a lambda expression inside of it does not save the context, that's why it did not work.